# Cypress: set attribute value

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have just started exploring Cypress and came across such a problem: is it possible to select a concrete attribute and change its value like in Selenium with the help of `JavascriptExecutor`? For example lets take this simple piece of code

```
input id="mapsearch" type="textbox" class="form-control" name="address" test=""
```

Is it possible to get the test attribute and assign my own value?

Comment: You can use  html5 data attributes.  data-test="test". And then you can select this based on this attribute value.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes. Anything you can do in JavaScript is possible within Cypress tests. For the html above, you could do this within Cypress using [`.invoke()`](https://on.cypress.io/invoke):

```
cy.get('input[test]')
  .invoke('attr', 'test', 'my new value')
  .should('have.attr', 'test', 'my new value')
```

Cypress uses jQuery under the hood, so you can invoke any function in jQuery like this. You could alternatively use plain JavaScript after yielding the input using [`.then()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/then.html#Syntax):

```
cy.get('input[test]').then(function($input){
    $input[0].setAttribute('test', 'my new value')
  })
  .should('have.attr', 'test', 'my new value')
```

Answer (score 3):

While Jennifer's answer actually works for most of the input elements, there is an exception especially when the application only takes the input value on `input/change event` as invoke will not trigger the event.

I had such experience and the below code worked for me.

**In Commands.js**:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('inputChange', (input, value) => {
    const nativeInputValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(
      window.HTMLInputElement.prototype,
      'value'
    ).set

    const changeInputValue = inputToChange => newValue => {
      nativeInputValueSetter.call(inputToChange[0], newValue)
      inputToChange[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('input', {
        newValue,
        bubbles: true,
        composed: true
      }))
    }

    return cy.get(input).then(input => {
      changeInputValue(input)(value)
    })
  })
```

And in **Tests**:

```
   cy.get('[data-test="voy-lat-long-input"]')
        .then(input => cy.inputChange(input, Longtitude))
```

Comment: You should also be able to just add `.trigger('change')` after the `.invoke()` to, well, trigger the change event (or  `.trigger('input')` if it's an input event that you need).

Comment: Yeh, it is also an option. That's the very first thing I tried but It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

**You can try with this**

```
cy.get('.class/#id').type('type your new value', { force: true });
```

Comment: .type() types into the input for me but then hangs and timeouts. With and without force.

Comment: _.type_ will write in the input, probably with the consequence to change the _value_ attribute. The OP asked how to change a custom attribute (_test_).