# Setting attribute in Cypress

Tags: cypress

Can't figure out from Cypress docs how to change attribute of a specific element in my integration test.

Basically, would like to achieve the below:

```
document.getElementById('my-id').setAttribute('data-test', 'new-value')
```

Do you think it's possible?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe this topic has the answer you are looking for:
[Cypress: set attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47131842/cypress-set-attribute-value)

As mentionned in that topic, you can either:

- use `invoke`
- get the jQuery element by using `.then(($el) => { $el.doSomeJqueryThings() }`