# cypress: set value of angular material slider

Tags: angular-material, cypress

I am testing code that contains a mat-slider and I cannot get the test to set the value of the slider or move the slider.

I have tried various things, including these:

[Cypress: set attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47131842/cypress-set-attribute-value)

[How do interact correctly with a range input (slider) in Cypress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55023428/how-do-interact-correctly-with-a-range-input-slider-in-cypress)

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1570

No luck so far. Is there any other way?

The problem is that mat-slider is not an input=range... When moving the slider, the attribute that changes is the aria-valuenow. I tried setting that and triggering change or input but it hasn't worked so for.

Do I need to work with mousemove etc.?

Answer (score 2):

You could set the focus to the slider and use the arrow keys to increase/decrease the value.
If you have a slider with label "Some slider", initial value of 0 and step 1, the following code would get your value to 3 :).

```
cy.findByLabelText("Some slider")
  .focus()
  .type("{rightarrow}{rightarrow}{rightarrow}");
```

These are all the keys you can use:
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type#Arguments
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/focus#Usage

I am using this in a project on cypress 7.4.0

Comment: Thanks so much. I've been struggling with that for hours, trying different ways to "fake" a keyboard event. Never would've thought of this and unlike the other attempts, this worked right away.